# display image from database using LINQ in dotnetnuke

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, file-upload, dotnetnuke

I want to display image stored in my database on my page. I am using LINQ to SQL to store and receieve data from database.

This is how i stored my image in database.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" class="form-control" onchange="readURL(this)" /><br />

if (fileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + fileUpload.FileName);
                newOrder.Image = Server.MapPath("~/images/") + fileUpload.FileName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

images are stored like : C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myApp\images\333.JPG

**this is how i get data from database**

```
myAppDBDataContext db = new myAppDBDataContext();

Order order = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID ==  id_order).FirstOrDefault();
```

**tried this, but it's not working**

```
<asp:Image ID="image" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Image></li>
```

**code behind**

```
image.ImageUrl = order.Image;
```

Please help!

Thank you!

**SOLUTION**

This is the solution, works for me.

```
if (fileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string file_name = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + file_name);
                newOrd.Image = "/images/" + file_name;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Does the image actually exist in the `/images` folder? Is `order` not null? Is `order.Image` not null or empty. Does the browser give a 404? Is the images folder accessible to the public? There are a lot of possible answers... Without more info it is impossible to say.

Comment: @fokz8 check that the image actually exists at the given location and check that the path is stored correctly in the database. As far as how to use the asp.net Image control, you seem to be doing that correctly. When you use chrome debugger to inspect the image element, what is the path that src is set to?

Comment: image exists in the given location and path is stored like i posted above. When i run firebug, i can see image location in src of the image, but when i hover over it, it says "failed do load the given URL" @peggy

Comment: ok just figured it out, that url needs to end only with "images/333.jpg" , not whole path... @peggy